# What's the meaning of "feed" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is a comment from a poster made on an [article](http://www.salon.com/2011/10/26/why_i_refuse_to_text_message/) about *texting*:

> That's my issue with it. I have Tweeted nearly a thousand times. I have texted like 20 times, and only at gunpoint.
>
> It's prolly great for sending pure data, here is Joe's address, see you at the corner of this and that, the project is finished, please call me tomorrow. That sort of stuff.
>
> It is going to change the brains on the kids are being **fed** this stuff for sure though. Will that be good? Who knows, but most everyone will be in the same boat, so it will become like stupid tattoos, everyone will have one, so who cares?

What does *feed* mentioned above mean? I've looked it up in the dictionaries and the closest definition I found is from OALD, but I'm not quite sure if it's correct:

> 8 [transitive]
> **feed something**
> to satisfy a need, desire, etc. and keep it strong
> For drug addicts, the need to feed the addiction takes priority over everything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the past tense of feed (fed) is being used to describe the flow of the text messages into the consciousness of young people. It is not implying that the young people "need" to be fed the messages, just simply that they are growing up with the text messages and more broadly, communication style of short text messages and how that could alter their growth. In this case, it's being used as a verb.

The analogy is that being fed cakes early in life can lead to obesity and/or diabetes.

The original author is implying that style of communication may be damaging the intellectual health of growing young minds.